# looping using while stop in first iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a bisection calculation using python with a loop condition.
the loop stops with 2 conditions, reaching a maximum iteration or maximum error.

but when I run, it always ends with 2 iterations.

when I delete the maximum error requirement, the iteration runs up to the maximum iteration
but when I delete the iteration requirement, iterates only 2 times.

Please help me. Thank you.

```
def bisection(f, Xl, Xu, max_eA, iteration):
    x_l = Xl
    x_u = Xu
    eA = 0
    Xr = (x_l + x_u)/2
    total_iter = 0

    if f(Xl)*f(Xu) >= 0:
        print("Bisection method fails.")
        return None

    while eA < max_eA and total_iter < iteration+1:
        print("iteration", total_iter+1)
        xr_old = Xr
        print("xr old",xr_old)
        Xr = (x_l + x_u)/2
        print("Xr now", Xr)
        f_xr = f(Xr)
        if     f_xr == 0:
            print("Found exact solution.")
            print("Xr fix", Xr)
            return Xr
        elif f(x_l)*f_xr < 0:
            x_l = x_l
            x_u = Xr
            print("x_l use",x_l)
            print("x_u use",x_u)
        elif f(x_l)*f_xr > 0:
            x_l = Xr
            x_u = x_u
        else:
            print("Bisection method fails.")
            return None
        xr_new = Xr
        print("xr new",xr_new)
        print("xr old 2", xr_old)
        print("ea use",eA)
        eA = abs((xr_new-xr_old)/xr_new)
        print("max ea",max_eA)
        print("eA after calculate", eA)
        total_iter=total_iter+1
    return (x_l + x_u)/2

f = lambda x:  ((10000000 * (1.2 ** x)) / ((1.2 ** x) - 1))\
           +\
           ((-10000000*x) / ((1.2 ** x) - 1))\
           +\
           10000000
bisection(f,5,10,0.0001,20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code iterates only two times because in the second iteration the value of `eA` becomes greater than `max_eA`, and that is obvious.
After removing the condition of `eA` from the while loop you will get the desired output for 21 iterations.

The output of your code is

```
iteration 1
xr old 7.5
Xr now 7.5
xr new 7.5
xr old 2 7.5
ea use 0
max ea 0.0001
eA after calculate 0.0
iteration 2
xr old 7.5
Xr now 8.75
x_l use 7.5
x_u use 8.75
xr new 8.75
xr old 2 7.5
ea use 0.0
max ea 0.0001
eA after calculate 0.14285714285714285
```

As you can see from the output, in the second iteration the value of `eA` is `0.14285714285714285` and the value of `max_ea` is `0.0001`. So, the while loop fails.

Comment: but when I run up to 5 iterations, the value of `eA` is:

    - 0
    - 0.142857143
    - 0.076923077
    - 0.037037037
    - 0.018181818

all values above`max_eA (0.00001)`

and I need a stop condition `max_eA`

Comment: Thank you for your help. So i change my condition to `while eA > max_eA and total_iter < iteration+1` . but instead nothing appeared

Comment: Because if you see, in the first iteration `eA` = `0.0` is smaller than `max_eA` = `0.0001`. So the loop terminates in the first attempt itself. Kindly upvote my answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: But if i use `while eA > max_eA and total_iter < iteration+1` , `eA = 0` and `max_eA = 0.0001` . isn't the program supposed to run its operations? Because `0>0.00001` .

Comment: Buddy, you are on the wrong track, `0>0.00001`. is false. You can verify this in python with the code `print(0>0.00001)` the answer would be false.

Comment: aaahhh , I understand , thank you very much for your help . sorry for how long I understand .

And , can you help me how to get eA calculation started on the second iteration?

Comment: Sorry buddy, but i can't seem to get your program properly. I can help you with the syntax errors or logical errors as i did above, but i can't help you with the calculation as i am not sure what it is exactly about.

Comment: I am glad that i could help you. keep going you can solve it. If you get struck with any logical or syntax error, don't forget to ask.